# content rotation on rtl

Tags: html, css

Iam new to Css and Html.I have a problem,iam building a multilanguage site where when i select Arabic language,the content should be moved to right?All is fine expect there is a column where i show prices.The prices are in format as given;
600 TPs = 7 and

1800 TPs = 21

but after changing the language it becomes,
TPs = 7 600
and
TPs = 21 1800

The following style i have applied on selecting Arabic Language

```
<style>
        .ar{
        direction:rtl;
        margin-right:20px;
        }
        .ar_fl{
        float:right !important;
        }
        .ar hr
        {
          margin-left:31px !important;
        }
        </style>
```

how to solve this?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You show us how it becomes, but you don't tell how you need it to be shown. :)

Comment: sir it should be shown as; 600 TPs = 7 and

1800 TPs = 21

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, didnt get it at first. 
You need to set block (or table column), which provide prices direction: ltr, and thats all. If you say class/id if this block/ column I can tell you CSS code you need to write.

Comment: sir its basically a div with inline css,<div style='width:102px;float:left;margin-top:10px'>

Comment: Thank you very much sir.its done now.I have applied direction=ltr to this div and its done as I wanted it to be.

Comment: Ok I'm glad it works. I recomment it as answer for future generations, check it as accepted please.

Comment: Consider setting the `xml:lang` attribute in your page using [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), then use `[lang=ar] div` or whatever element your try to style. This will ensure your page is known as arabic language. You can read [Working with language in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/language-decl/) page for quick overview on i18n topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set block, which provide prices with this CSS:

```
direction: ltr;
```

And thats all. I recommend you to use classes instead of pure css in html.
Glad that it helps.